# Can a video game potentially detect arduino leonardo?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, keyboard

If I automated an action in a video game through arduino leonardo, can it be detected? Things like autohotkey can be easily detected, however i would expect an arduino would be far more difficult. How easy/difficult would it be detect?

Comment: it all depends on the game, and on the controller that you are emulating ..... for example  if the game is a first person shooter and the arduino is pulling the trigger exactly every 95 ms then the game may be able to determine that you are not pressing the keyboard manually

Comment: It would be little use to only check for Arduino's. You would in some way have to check the player's behaviour and estimate if it's 'human', which works for any type of automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nigh on impossible. True the game could look to see if there is a specific VID/PID combination visible to the computer, but that is probably not going to happen (and anyway you can change it).  As far as the game is concerned, input from a keyboard is input from a keyboard, whether that keyboard has buttons or a piece of code it really can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

First you'll need to define how you plan to inject the new input signal, into the data "packets" as a spoof of controller signals, or just jumping the switches?

In the context of any modern gaming console, it could be detected. Easily. Consoles and controllers use any number of proprietary protocols which sync.commands to improve response and reduce controller lag. If you're just jumping the switches, then no, you could simulate hadouken and probably get away with it just fine.

If you're referencing PC gaming, then that would be hard if not impossible with the variance of input control available.  The best deterrent would be the security of the game software itself and the genre of the gaming. Some games actively encourage Hotkeys.